# Should we 'accept' answers in the private beta phase?

Tags: discussion

As the private beta is about 'priming' the site with questions, should we accept answers? Or should we wait a while to give public beta users a chance?

Comment: During beta or post beta doesn't matter - if it answers the question being asked accept it

Comment: @ZachSaucier Would you care to elaborate?

Comment: I think that you should wait a while before accepting answers, as you should wait for a more better response and give others time to answer! But if you get the response you wanted, then accept, just try waiting a while.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, if you ask a question and get a great answer, you can accept it.  If you get an even better answer later, you can change the accepted answer.

That having been said, accepting an answer is optional.  It's optional now, and it's optional after the beta opens up to the public.  So please don't ask people to accept an answer.  The system reminds them automatically that they can accept an answer if they want.

Answer (score 4):

You can always change the accepted answer, so I don't see why we shouldn't accept answers right now. We  should accept what we believe is worth accepting and we can change it afterwards, of we see a better answer

Answer (score 4):

Here is a pretty good discussion of this issue:

> [**Not so fast! (When should I accept my answer?)**](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer)

Should be relevant here, too. The primary concern is that the likelihood of any additional answers is reduced once an accepted answer is displayed.
This can be a problem if an early answer is not the best answer, or even in some cases if it is inaccurate or even wrong.

To get the best answers, both to answer your question and for future reference, you want as many answers as possible.

A good reference on StackExchange Meta for accepting an answer is:

> [**How does accepting an answer work?**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: I was just going to post the same link. It had already worried me that we were getting accepted answers too quickly.

Answer (score -4):

Only the person asking the question can accept an answer.

When public beta users arrive, they will only be able to accept answers on their own questions.

Comment: I think the OP is asking about waiting for public beta users to add *new* answers.